# process one message per user

Tags: go, redis, queue, message-queue

I have a list in redis that I use as a queue. I push elements on the left and pop from the right.Requests from different users get pushed to the queue. I have a pool of goroutines that read a request off of the queue(POP) and processes them. I want to be able to only process one request per userId at a time. I have a ReadRequest() function running forever that POPs a request that has a userId. I need the request per user to be processed in the order they came in. I'm not sure how to implement this. Would I need a redis list per userId? If so how would I loop through all the lists processing the requests in them?

```
for i:=0; i< 5; i++{
  wg.Add(1)
  go ReadRequest(&wg)

}


func ReadRequest(){

   for{

      //redis pop request off list
       request:=MyRedisPop()
       fmt.Println(request.UserId)

      // only call Process if no other goroutine is processing a request for this user
      Process(request)



 time.sleep(100000)
     }

wg.Done()

}
```

Comment: Yes, you'd want one list per user. You'd want to have one goroutine per list polling one list each.

Comment: @Adrian how would I start a goroutine per user queue

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking - you've shown in the quoted code that you know how to start a goroutine.

Comment: If a new user connects and creates a new list in redis, how will the go code know to start a new go routine?

Comment: If the lists aren't being created by the same application, you can poll redis on a regular cycle to check for new lists.

Comment: From your descripion it's not clear what exactly "processing" means. If it's OK for messages to be _kept pending_ in your application before processing them, you might pop a message and then shovel it to _something_ (a goroutine or whatever) which processes messages for specific user, and it queues this message locally _if_ it already processes a message for that user; as soon as it completes the processing, it takes the first saved message and goes on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo-code that you could use without creating multiple Redis lists:

```
// maintain a global map for all users
// if you see a new user, call NewPerUser() and add it to the list
// Then, send the request to the corresponding channel for processing
var userMap map[string]PerUser 

type PerUser struct {
    chan<- redis.Request // Whatever is the request type
    semaphore *semaphore.Weighted // Semaphore to limit concurrent processing
}

func NewPerUser() *PerUser {
    ch := make(chan redis.Request)
    s := semaphore.NewWeighted(1) // One 1 concurrent request is allowed
    go func(){
        for req := range ch {
            s.Acquire(context.Background(), 1)
            defer s.Release(1)
            // Process the request here
        }
    }()
}
```

Please note that this is only a pseudo-code and I haven't tested whether it works.

Comment: How can I stop the go routine after a user is no longer connected

Comment: You can close the corresponding channel - it will exit the for loop and end the go-routine.